# How prevent from returning c_str

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write some general-purpose interfaces, that could be used in various platforms, such as Arduino, Windows, Linux are. But unfortunately, in some of these interfaces, I have to return a string. Therefore, I have chosen the `char const*` as a return type for these functions. For instance:

```cpp
class Plugin {
  virtual char const* uuid() const = 0;
}
```

But such an approach causes the problem. For example, if some derived class uses `Qt` library, it's more comfortable for the user to use `QString` for keeping the `uuid`. But in that case, there's a problem in returning required fields.

My question is about a suggestion in what type to return in such a situation?

If there isn't any other, how to easily convert `std::string` or `QString` or other string types into `char const*` type string?

Comment: Why don't you make it a template method and return whatever the client wants as long as its convertible?

Comment: Why not use `std::string` instead of `char*`? `std::string` is the standard string type in C++. `QString` has [`toStdString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString) and [`fromStdString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString) methods

Comment: @RemyLebeau Arduino doesn't support it I think

Comment: You cannot deliver to everyone. If you want a library for Arduino, make it for Arduino. If you want a library for C++, use proper C++. It's just not feasible to cater to every possible flavour and framework in C++.

Comment: @arsdever Yes it does. It's an old port of STL though.

Comment: @SombreroChicken thanks for the nice suggestion. I will try to use the approach you suggested. It seems to be quite reasonable and useful.

Comment: Arduino does not provide a standard C++ library, and if a compatible implementation exists, it's hard to find. For this reason, you can hardly say that Arduino is a C++ platform.

Comment: @arsdever Have you installed the standard library kit?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's somewhere ~98 - ~11 in its implementation. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I even don't want to try. Why force the user to install some libraries just to use the interface provided by you? I'm trying to keep myself in neutral zone.

Comment: @TedLyngmo As far as I know, the IDE provided by Arduino has no standard library support. If memory serves, I had to implement `new` my self. And the site doesn't seem to offer any kind of standard C++ library implementation. Where did you find yours? Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Are you providing libraries to some implementor? If not, the user will not have a clue. You install what you need.

Comment: Also, there's not a problem regarding only the Arduino board. What if there is another platform without the support of `std::string` do I have to write or force the user to write the `std::string` for his project only to make it possible to use my interface?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't understand what you are asking. Maybe we are misunderstanding each other. Does Arduino have some C++ standard library implementation that I don't know about?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are correct in that it does not provide one out-of-the-box, but [Arduino STL](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/arduino-stl) exists. `new` is now included and fully supported by the compiler :-)

Comment: If you want maximum compatibility you can take a pointer to an array and it's size and copy the string into that buffer. Then null terminate it or return the size. It's a bad system, but it's one anyone should be able to support.

Comment: If it's uuid, why not define a struct and return that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question unclear because it needs lifetime rules for your string.

Comment: If you go for compatibility, stay away from the Arduino IDE. The port of STL is a good effort, but turn on warnings and you'll have a lifetime of reading ahead of you. It does help tremendously when developing on a standard conforming platform wanting to port *to* Arduino though.